# how to select ionic slide item without clicking

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ion-slides

I'm working on an android app with the Ionic 3 framework.
My app's main page should have 3 horizontal slides:

[like this sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Acc.png)

And I want to select the 3 slide items that are in the center without clicking.
I have a button that will redirect the user to another page with the 3 selected items:

[like this sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMdu9.png)

Is it possible to do that?

Need your help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want move one slide page to second slide page than try this...
You can redirect page using slides index number.

home.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
 selector: 'page-manhomeslider',
 templateUrl: 'manhomeslider.html',
})

export class ManhomesliderPage {
@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

}

ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad ManhomesliderPage')
}

goToSlide2() {
  this.slides.slideTo(1, 500);
}
```

}

home.html

```
<ion-slide>
    <ion-buttons class="btnend" end>
              <button (click)="goToSlide2()" ion-button round>
               <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
              </button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>
    <h2>slide page 2</h2>
</ion-slide>
```